# How do I use the same list on a pop-up menu using the GUIDE on MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, popupmenu

In MATLAB, I am exporting a list of names from an excel file 'list.xls' into a variable 'Columns', so that this list is displayed into pop-up menues 'popUp1' and 'popUp2' with handles. The problem is that the list is displayed only in popUp1, and I receive an error for popUp2. My code is as follows:

```
function popUp1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 handles = guidata(hObject);
 [~,Columns]=xlsread('list.xls'); %get the list
 set(hObject,'String',Columns); %set(display) list on popUp1 menu
 handles.columns=Columns;
 handles=guidata(hObject);
 guidata(hObject,handles);

 if ispc && Isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'),get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
 end


function popUp2_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
 Columns=get(handles.columns,'String'); %gets the list from handles
 set(hObject,'String',Columns); %set(display) the list on popUp2 menu

 if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), set(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
 end
```

When I use 'Columns=get(handles.columns,'String');' in the Callback function, the error does not display, but still popUp2 is empty.

Honestly, I am very confused about the whole 'handles' thing, so any explanation on how they work will be highly appreciated.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I can't test it right now, but I think you should remove both instances of `handles=guidata(hObject);` in popU1_CreateFcn. This part of code loads the handles variable associated with hObject. It is unnecessary in the first line, as handles is already an argument to the function. In the second instance, it is actually harmful, as it negates the line `handles.columns=Columns`, as handles is reset to the state it had before popU1_CreateFcn was called.

Have a closer look at the documentation http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html :

```
To change the data managed by guidata:
1) Get a copy of the data with the command  data = guidata(object_handle).
2) Make the desired changes to data.
3) Save the changed version of data with the command  guidata(object_handle,data).
```